# How to created a delegated class instead of a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to implement this tip https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id55 in order to write some non-pythonic code, where I'd use a class with delegation (`DelegatedLoanContract`) instead of a subclass (`LoanContract(ContractsWriter)`). But I'm getting: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'DelegatedLoanContract' and 'str'`. Any idea how to solve it?

Here's the code: https://github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/fun-with-delegation

Here's also a minimal version of the code:

```
class ContractsWriter:
    def __init__(self, signee_1, signee_2):
        self.signee_1 = signee_1
        self.signee_2 = signee_2
        self.contract_rules = []

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            self.contract_rules.append(other)
            return self
        elif isinstance(other, list):
            self.contract_rules.extend(other)
            return self
        else:
            raise NotImplemented('Invalid rule.')

class DelegatedLoanContract:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__['_contract'] = ContractsWriter(*args, **kwargs)
        self._contract.header = 'loan'

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self._contract, item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self._contract, key, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loan_contract = DelegatedLoanContract('Alan', 'John')
    loan_contract += 'Signee_1 will load 2,000 EUR to Signee_2.'
```

Comment: Include a [mcve] in your question. A link to your code is not sufficient.

Comment: You need to post code in the question itself, not just as an external link. (Also, asking people not to downvote isn't a great idea.)

Comment: Also, don't tag `python-2.7` if you're using Python 3.

Comment: I fixed all now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about delegation, you have to write `__iadd__` method of `DelegatedLoanContract` that will delegate to `__add__` method of `ContractsWriter`:

```
class DelegatedLoanContract:
    ... # your code here

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self._contract += other
        return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loan_contract = DelegatedLoanContract('Alan', 'John')
    loan_contract += 'Signee_1 will load 2,000 EUR to Signee_2.'
    print(loan_contract._contract.contract_rules)
    # prints ['Signee_1 will load 2,000 EUR to Signee_2.']
```

Comment: But why don't `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` work for all of the undefined methods at once, including dunder methods? I thought that not finding `__add__` as a method of DelegatedLoanContract would invoke `__setattr__('__add__', 'Signee_1 will load 2,000 EUR to Signee_2.')`...

Comment: Is it because `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` only look for self.variables, and they ignore methods?

Comment: Damn, I wish I found out earlier. I wasted quite a lot of time with this. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't access magic methods, because `Variable names with double leading underscores are “mangled” to provide a simple but effective way to define class private variables.`, right? They can only be accessed with `super()` or from `.__dict__`

Comment: No, this statement is about variables defined like `__variable`, without double underscores at the end. These variables can be accesses via `_classname__variable`. Magic methods don't follow this rule.

Comment: I found a doc that can explain something about it, see it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__). Also read the _Note_ under `__getattribute__`